# { "errorType": "java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError" } in AWS Lambda Function

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, aws-lambda

I have a service developed in SpringBoot and to be deployed in AWS. In the LambdaHandler, Spring Applucation class name is given to run the SpringBoot Application when in AWS Environment.

But, am getting below error in AWS Lambda console, when I try to test by giving i/p in JSON format as Test Event and try to insert record into DB on invoking the Lambda Function

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Error loading class com.example.lambda.LambdaHandler",
  "errorType": "java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError"
}
```

Here is my LambdaHandler Class

```
public class LambdaHandler implements RequestHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> {

    private static SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> handler;

    static {
        try {
            handler = SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.getAwsProxyHandler(SpringBootApplication.class);
        } catch (ContainerInitializationException e) {
            // if we fail here. We re-throw the exception to force another cold start
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not initialize Spring Boot Application", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public AwsProxyResponse handleRequest(AwsProxyRequest awsProxyRequest, Context context) {
        return handler.proxy(awsProxyRequest, context);
    }
}
```

Here is my main Application Class

```
  public class SpringBootApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApplication.class, args);
        }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you initialize the handler in the `handleRequest` method? I.e. first check if `handler` is null, then initialize it, otherwise use `handler` immediately.
`
handleRequest(...) {
  if (handler == null) {
    handler = ...
  }
  // do something with handler
}
`

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions being thrown in a static context cause this error.

Change your code to the following so that you can see *why* it's throwing an exception in the first place, then address that error:

```
. . .
static {
    try {
        handler = SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.getAwsProxyHandler(SpringBootApplication.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // if we fail here. We re-throw the exception to force another cold start
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not initialize Spring Boot Application", e);
    }
}
. . .
```

Always be cautious when loading things statically.

Comment: @sar Well OP never shared the stack trace so there's not much opportunity to help; If you're having a similar issue, I advise you also print the stack trace and share it in a new question.